# Cheerio Package node.js: Extracting an attribute for all of html data

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, attributes, cheerio

essentially, [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvq0H.png) the page source I am interested in.

I am trying to get the value of the "data-productsku" for all of the items in the whole of the page source. So far I have done this:

```
var sku = ($(".productListItem  .itemContainer span .itemOverlay").attr('data-productsku'))

var xText= sku.text();


console.log(xText)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and outputs nothing in the log.

Intended output  - where x is the rest of the skus in the source. 

`062029
x
x
x
x
x`

Comment: try with jqurey ready method:
$(function(){
var sku = ($(".productListItem  .itemContainer span .itemOverlay").attr('data-productsku'))

var xText= x.text();


console.log(xText);
});

Comment: @SupunPraneeth Didn't make a change unfortunately, also sorry varxText  = sku.text(), this wasn't the issue on the code being ran, edited above too.

Comment: tell me if i am wrong: you want to get the text in any element that have attribute call `data-productsku` right ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth that is correct, so it would be the 6 numbers all the time [different ones of course haha]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-productsku]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-productsku'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="productListMain" class="listProducts productList" data-infinitescroll="">

  <li class="productListItem ">
    <span class="itemContainer">

  <a class="itemImage" href="/product/multi-adidas-originals-yung-1/062069/" data-e2e="product-listing">
      <span class="thumbnail overlay-thumbnail">
   
   </span>
    </a>
    <span class="itemOverlay " data-productsku="062069">
 <span class="itemQuickView quickView btn btn-default" title="Quick Buy">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <style>
       .cls-1 {
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="BASKET" class="cls-1" d="M128.167,87H150l-14,55H64L50,87H71L99.583,58.417ZM70.8,134h58.4L139,95H61Zm46.367-47L99.583,69.417,82,87h35.167Z"/>
</svg>
&nbsp;Quick Buy
 </span>
    </span>

    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nothing outputted

Comment: https://pastebin.com/iZ7YJAxZ this is for one of the items, the rest are the same but with different values.

Comment: @3.14159265432 sorry my bad, check again

Comment: sorry not sure I understand, is it node JS? or..? Do I load that html into const $ [which is currently the entire source/ body]?

Comment: still no output, I think it cannot locate it? because all the other elements work and output, idk.

Comment: have you checked in your console ?

Comment: Did I mess up somewhere in syntax or solution doesn't work?

Comment: sorry i didn't see the link, i was waiting for you to send the link :D. I'll check

Comment: why there' a extra bracket end of the file ?

Comment: it is a part of another function[so marks the end of that function] , so your function is within a larger one.

Comment: this is very hard to look when i can't run the code, so if your project is an open source project send me the git link and i can take a look. and jquery code is ok and in the front end its work fine

Comment: you can test by putting this page source view-source:https://www.size.co.uk/campaign/New+In/?facet:new=latest&sort=latest into var and trying with my code shown in pastebin above

Comment: Anyone got a solution ?